# Javascript "getSelection" only if it's in a certain div

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to collect what people are selecting on our site. Currently, it works EVERYWHERE, and I don't want that. I only want it if they are selecting in a certain DIV.

it's basically a simple modification to a script I found.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function appendCopyright() {
    var theBody = document.getElementsByClassName("sbReview")[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var copyrightLink = '<br /><br /> - Read more at: <a href="'+document.location.href+'">'+document.location.href+'</a><br />&copy;2012 <? printf($product. ' & ' .$spOrganization); ?>';
    var copytext = selection + copyrightLink;
    var extra = document.createElement("div");
    extra.style.position="absolute";
    extra.style.left="-99999px";
    theBody.appendChild(extra);
    extra.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(extra);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    theBody.removeChild(extra);
    },0);
}
document.oncopy = appendCopyright;
```

I tried modifying `selection = window.getSelection();` but it just broke it :(

Basically, I want the above code, ONLY to work in a certain div, not the whole `body`

Comment: let me get the aim of this code correct, you want to display a copyright if a user selects a specific chunk of text?

Comment: @DerekAdair - that pretty much nails it. Only if it's from a div, call it `<div class="sbReview">` - everything else should NOT contain the copyright if copy/pasted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you shouldn't use `document.oncopy`, instead try using `div.oncopy` where `div` is the div element you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

`var selection = getSelection().toString();` is your solution - `getSelection()` returns a Selection object and you can get the string just by using `.toString()` method. More properties and methods of Selection object could be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection

Comment: ok i understand, that's not the problem because `selection + copyrightLink` uses `.toString()` to cast the type.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**Mozilla JS docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection)   the selection class has a method [**containsNode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection/containsNode).  The following should work.

```
function appendCopyright() {
    var theBody = document.getElementsByClassName("sbReview")[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    // HERE's THE GOODS
    // set aPartlyContained to true if you want to display this
    // if any of your node is selected
    if(selection.containsNode(aNode, aPartlyContained)){
        var copyrightLink = '<br /><br /> - Read more at: <a href="'+document.location.href+'">'+document.location.href+'</a><br />&copy;2012 <? printf($product. ' & ' .$spOrganization); ?>';
        var copytext = selection + copyrightLink;
        var extra = document.createElement("div");
        extra.style.position="absolute";
        extra.style.left="-99999px";
        theBody.appendChild(extra);
        extra.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(extra);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            theBody.removeChild(extra);
        },0);
    }
}
document.oncopy = appendCopyright;
```

Comment: note that this is not a generic solution, but should get you headed in the right direction.